# node.js - for .. await - end of execution detection

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I need help figuring out Promise inside a `for ... await` loop.

Code that reads from `text.txt` line by line and logs result to console:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

async function processLineByLine() {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('text.txt');

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fileStream,
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });
    
    for await (const line of rl) {
        console.log(line);
    }

    console.log('THIS LINE IS EXECUTED BEFORE EVERY LINE OF FILE IS SHOWN');
}

processLineByLine();
```

**Question**.

How can I fire some action once the `for ... await` execution is complete (i.e. every line of `text.txt` has been read)?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Full code below. It tried to read JSON lines from LF-separated text file and inserts them into MySQL 8 JSON collection.

```js
const mysqlx = require('@mysql/xdevapi');
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

async function processLineByLine(coll) {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fileStream,
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    for await (const line of rl) {
        coll.add(line)
            .execute()
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Done line')
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    }

    console.log('You should only see this after "Done line" is finished printing.');
}

mysqlx.getSession('mysqlx://user:password@localhost:33060/json')
    .then(session => {
        const schema = session.getSchema('json');
        return schema.existsInDatabase()
            .then(exists => {
                if (exists) {
                    return schema;
                }
            })
            .then(schema => {
                return schema.createCollection('json_docs', {reuseExisting: true});
            })
            .then(collection => {
                processLineByLine(collection);
            })
    });
```

Comment: Uh, have you tried putting that action after the loop?!

Comment: It's done the way you did it. What problem do you have with this code? If you need to log after the loop (the wording is unclear) then insert another console.log after it.

Comment: The problem is that 'THIS LINE IS EXECUTED BEFORE EVERY LINE OF FILE IS SHOWN' message is shown before every line of the file is shown

Comment: I cannot reproduce. `console.log(line)` never executes after the loop has finished and the closing log has been printed. Is this your complete code, or does your actual code have some more asynchronous parts?

Comment: @Bergi I added the full code. I am seeing 'You should only see this after "Done line" is finished printing.' message before any of 'Done line'.

Comment: Ah, yes, yes of course - `execute` is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for await` loop is waiting for each line to become available in the read stream. It then executes the loop body. This loop body schedules some asynchronous work - adding a row to your database - but **does not wait for it**. The `.then()` callback will log `Done line` after the database insertion finished. When the file stream ends, the log statement in the following line is printed, no matter how many database requests are still in flight.

You usually want to avoid calling `.then()` when working with `async`/`await`. If you use `await` in the loop body, the iterations will wait for each row to be inserted into the database before processing the next line, and you got your proper sequential execution:

```
async function processLineByLine(coll) {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fileStream,
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    for await (const line of rl) {
        await coll.add(line).execute();
//      ^^^^^
        console.log('Done line')
    }

    console.log('Done file');
}
```

(Notice I also remove the `.catch()` - you probably don't want to ignore errors but make the entire function call fail)

The same applies to the rest of the code - you should use `async`/`await` instead of `.then()`:

```
async function main() {
    try {
        const session = await mysqlx.getSession('mysqlx://user:password@localhost:33060/json');
        let schema = session.getSchema('json');
        const exists = await schema.existsInDatabase();
        if (!exists) {
            schema = undefined; // this is weird, but I kept the behavior of your code
        }
        const collection = await schema.createCollection('json_docs', {reuseExisting: true});
        await processLineByLine(collection);
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}
main();
```